# How to remove a specific, duplicated line within a file?

Tags: text-processing, uniq, duplicate

I'm looking for a way to remove one specific line from a bunch of files, but only if it occurs more than once in that file. Other lines should be kept, even if they are duplicates.

For example, a file like this where I would like to remove the duplicates of `AAA`

```
AAA
BBB
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

should become

```
AAA
BBB
BBB
CCC
```

I guess I should use `sed` but I have no idea how to write the command.

Comment: `BBB` is also duplicated, but you want a solution that takes `AAA` as an argument?

Comment: Is the first occurrence of `AAA` always on the first line?

Comment: I know I've answered this several times.  Here's one: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6248/4676

Comment: AAA would be an argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '0,/^AAA$/b;//d'
```

That is, let everything through (`b` branches off like a `continue`) up to the first `AAA` (from the 0th line (that is even before the first line) and the first one matching `/^AAA$/` (which could be the first line)), and then for the remaining lines, delete every occurrence of `AAA` (an empty `//` pattern reuses the last pattern).

GNU `sed` is needed for the `0` address (and the ability to have other commands after the `b` one in the same expression, though that could be easily worked around in other implementations by using two `-e` expressions)

With `awk`:

```
awk '$0 != "AAA" || !n++'
```

(or for a regexp pattern: `awk '!/^AAA$/ || !n++'`)

a shorthand for:

```
awk '! (&0 == "AAA" && count > 0) {print; count++}'
```

Comment: I like that `awk` shorthand.  Took a second to parse this early in the day, but I've filed that away for future use.

Comment: +1 for the genius `sed` solution

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around your `sed` solution. It does work, but how does it know how to delete only the `AAA` line?

Comment: @neXus, see if the new edit makes it clearer.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you. I didn't know that the empty `//d` pattern reused the previous one. I assumed it deleted everything. This makes much more sense. Beautiful solution!

Answer (score 2):

[Stéphane Chazelas' `awk` solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388353/116858) is beautiful:

```
awk '!/AAA/ || !n++' file.in
```

This may be generalized as

```
awk '$0 !~ pattern || !n++' pattern="$pattern" file.in
```

for a given shell variable `$pattern` containing some regular expression.

If `$pattern` contains backslashes, these need to be escaped (`\\`), or you may use

```
P="$pattern" awk '$0 !~ ENVIRON["P"] || !n++' file.in
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exchange buffers each time you encounter that line, if the pattern space contains the same line delete it, else retrieve the line from the hold buffer:

```
sed -e '/^AAA$/{x;//d;g' -e'}' infile
```

or

```
sed '/^AAA$/{
x
//d
g
}' infile
```